# Web Accessibility Rapid Application Development Test Assertions

Tags: testing, automation, accessibility

I have opted for thesis work in Masters course. I have been a software test automation engineer for 3 years before I came back to academics. I would want to address a topic in my thesis which will be of great use to the testing community. One of the idea which crossed my mind was to write a test assertion plugin (based on W3C guidelines - WCAG) for popular open source continuous integration softwares like CruiseControl, Hudson etc. which will run WCAG accessibility test assertions on every web source code the moment it is checked in to the source control and provide suggestions on non-conformance, so that the developers can correct the accessibility related issues before the build goes in to production. The plugin is intended to be open source. Do you guys think it will be a worthy tool for investing research time on it? If not, are there any other problems related to test automation that we as a member of test community look forward to get addressed?

Thank you for your time and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This definitely sounds like a good project. I know that Visual Studio provides accessibility checks (just for ASP.NET though?) but something that could be used with CI would be valuable.